# ssh EOF in bash script - how to store value of command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scripting

I need to basically copy only the last created folder in a directory of many folders within an SSH session. I have the correct find command to do this, but I just can't seem to store the result within the SSH session. the `LATEST_FOLDER` variable is empty, and I've tried something like this also:

`cp -f arkOutput/$(find . -type d -exec stat --printf="%Y\t%n\n" {} \; | sort -n -r | head -1 | cut -f2 | cut -c 3-)/* /synology/data/${OUTPUT_PATH}/${i}/ark`

Here is the full ssh session code:

```
    ssh $USER@server.com << EOF
      cd /data/dev/${ARK_PATH}/
      ./gradlew bootRun --no-daemon;
      LATEST_FOLDER=$(find . -type d -exec stat --printf="%Y\t%n\n" {} \; | sort -n -r | head -1 | cut -f2 | cut -c 3-);
      cp -f arkOutput/${LATEST_FOLDER}/* /synology/data/${OUTPUT_PATH}/${i}/ark
EOF
```

the /data/dev dir only exists on the server I'm sshing into, so I can't really get that before hand and pass it in. the ./gradlew bootRun command creates the folder I'm interested in

Comment: hello, so that worked for the ssh local variable LATEST_FOLDER, however the ${ARK_PATH} and ${OUTPUT_PATH} are now no longer recognized. They were defined outside of the ssh session, earlier in the script. is it possible to still have those be defined within the SSH session when I do \EOF (like you suggested)?

Comment: The point being made was that the things in the HERE document are being evaluated. To stop the evaluation of the whole thing you can quote at least one character of the delimiter. You appear to be saying that you want **ome** of the document to be evaluated, but not all. In that case you need to quote the bits you don't want evaluated.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 please don't post answers in comments. Comments cannot be voted on so this circumvents the normal quality control processes of the site, and they can also discourage others from posting actual answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixing up the current way of doing things

```
ssh $USER@server.com << EOF
   cd /data/dev/${ARK_PATH}/
   ./gradlew bootRun --no-daemon
   LATEST_FOLDER=\$(find . -type d -exec stat --printf="%Y\t%n\n" {} \; | sort -n -r | head -1 | cut -f2 | cut -c 3-)
   cp -f arkOutput/\${LATEST_FOLDER}/* /synology/data/${OUTPUT_PATH}/${i}/ark
EOF
```

I am not sure if you want `${i}` or `\${i}` - I suspect the former.

### Second way

A different approach would be to split things into 2 or 3 ssh commands. E.G.

```
ssh "$USER@server.com" "cd /data/dev/${ARK_PATH}/ && ./gradlew bootRun --no-daemon"
LATEST_FOLDER=$(ssh "$USER@server.com" "find /data/dev/${ARK_PATH}/ -type d -exec stat --printf='%Y\t%n\n' {} + | sort -n -r | head -1 | cut -f2 | cut -c 3-" )
ssh "$USER@server.com" "cp -f /data/dev/${ARK_PATH}/arkOutput/${LATEST_FOLDER}/* /synology/data/${OUTPUT_PATH}/${i}/ark"
```

This might be a little more obvious.

### Third way

A third approach might be to just put the script on the server, and just pass the parameters to it.